# Can arping by IP but not MAC address

Tags: networking, ubuntu-12.04, arp

I have an interface that I can arping to by its IP, but not its MAC address:

```
# arping -i eth2 10.10.0.153
ARPING 10.10.0.153
60 bytes from 02:68:b3:29:da:98 (10.10.0.153): index=0 time=81.062 usec
60 bytes from 02:68:b3:29:da:98 (10.10.0.153): index=1 time=46.968 usec
60 bytes from 02:68:b3:29:da:98 (10.10.0.153): index=2 time=73.910 usec
60 bytes from 02:68:b3:29:da:98 (10.10.0.153): index=3 time=46.968 usec

# arping -i eth2 02:68:b3:29:da:98
ARPING 02:68:b3:29:da:98
(no reply)
```

I don't have this problem with other interfaces on my network. What are the possible issues that could cause this?

I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Is pinging by MAC address a requirement for you?

Answer (score 5):

```
arping -i eth2 10.10.0.153
```

Send out an ARP packet asking, "Who has the IP 10.10.0.153?"

```
arping -i eth2 02:68:b3:29:da:98
```

Sends out an IPv4 ping to the IP address 255.255.255.255 with the target MAC of 02:68:b3:29:da:98.

It is common nowadays to disable responding to broadcast pings. On a Linux system (well any, but I'm only providing a link for one), [you can re-enable replies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7458/14121) to broadcast IP addresses.

Comment: I do see outbound packets when pinging against a MAC, if I do this: `tcpdump -ennqti eth2 \( arp or icmp \)`. I just don't see any come back.

Comment: Oops, I messed up my filters. Let me post a new one with the right answer now that I realize what happened.